# Is it possible to avoid anaerobic 'burn' on ascents?

Tags: fitness, beginner, climbing, hills

As a total noob to cycling the thing that really kills me is hills steep enough I get into anaerobic territory. My general fitness lets me cycle for hours without really getting tired even working fairly hard, but my thighs have a pretty limited total amount of ascent in them which takes a long time to replenish.

I feel like on steeper hills (say 10% and above) I have to go anaerobic to get enough speed... if I shift down to my lowest gear at my regular cadence I am so slow I risk falling off, and of course the climb just takes much much longer anyway!

My beginner question is: should it be possible to get up most/all hills aerobically using gears, or is it a fundamental feature of cycling that you *will* end up burning, and you *will* find sometimes your legs just give out mid-hill until you improve your muscles/fitness?

Comment: Much like any physical activity, if you're not trained for it, it's going to be tough. Using gears judiciously helps, but a tough incline is going to be tough anyway you slice it.

Comment: What is your first gear (cog teeth, chainring teeth)?

Comment: The short answer is "yes". For example, I can go up 1:1 gradiants (45 degrees) on my load carrying quad without going anaerobic. I suspect you don't have low enough gears. If you're already in your lowest gear but find you have to work excessively hard to keep your pedal rpm up, you need lower gears. If not, change down and go more slowly.

Comment: I'm more finding i go so darn slowly I risk falling off! I've a MTB so in bottom gear even at decent cadence I'm not really moving!

Comment: @Móż - Maybe on a quad, but not on a bike.  As the OP suggests, you can easily get in a situation where you're going too slow to maintain balance.

Comment: Where do you find a 1:1 hill?!

Comment: @Mr.Boy you find a really steep hill, then go up it.  Very few roads exceed 25% and the steepest street in the southern hemisphere has a peak gradient of 35%   World's steepest public road is Bradford St in San Francisco with a 6.5 metre length at 39-40%.    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baldwin_Street#Controversy_of_claim

Comment: In Australia and NZ many small rural roads go straight up and over small obstacles like stopbanks (levee in France and the USA, I believe), and private driveways can be ridiculously steep. I've not found even 100m of hill that steep, but I found a stopbank in Queensland that had marks cut into it where the front end of motor vehicles had hit the road, and it took 4 people to push the quad up. Since I fixed the gearing I can ride up stuff like that. I've ridden a two wheel MTB with touring load on it up hills where a 24/38 bottom gear was not low enough but it's all I had (off road, on rock)

Comment: The [Maungatapu Track](https://crazybikelady.wordpress.com/2011/04/08/31-mar-2011-the-mammoth-challenge-that-was-the-murderous-maungatapu-track/) is one place that has a brief stretch of steep, rocky "road". 1500m of climbing in 40km, but a lot of that is old bush railway gradient. The [google gradient map is  peaky](https://www.google.com.au/maps/dir/-41.2904082,173.365386/-41.297106,173.5724593/@-41.3240331,173.188049,10.89z/data=!4m2!4m1!3e1)

Comment: Also, this is about fitness as much as gears. If you're already able to go so slowly that you can't balance, working on low-speed riding will help, but the long-term goal has to be building fitness, specifically peak power output. As a noob you're probably peaking between 250W and 350W, which is the sustained power output for a competitive rider. Their peaks are generally closer to 1000W, so they have 3-4x the power available when they need it (maybe only for 30s, but they can do 2x your power for a 10 minute climb).

Comment: Even our resident geriatrics (Andy and Daniel :-P) are likely more powerful than you by a significant margin. But that can change... being unfit means it's much easier to get big gains in fitness. For already-fit people doubling their sustained power output might be impossible, but for someone just starting to ride it's what you should expect to have happen.

Comment: You didn't mention how much you weigh - a crucial part of the gradient vs effort equation

Comment: @Móż Oy! I resemble that!

Answer (score 6):

Get an app like strava to log your rides, and see your progress on those climbs.

I have a climb near home which took three hours first time I did it.  I rested a bunch of times on the way up, and got passed by dozens of riders.

Over the last three years I've improved to the point I can do the climb in 40 minutes non-stop, still get passed but I'm passing others, some of whom look shattered.

Remember it never gets easier, you just go faster.  Some logging will help show you your improvements, because it never feels faster at the time.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question but is it considered OK to stop for a rest? In my naivety I imagine cyclists never stop mid climb, is that just from watching pro riders on TV?

Comment: Yes, and No.  Yes, in that its your ride - if it won't take away from your enjoyment, by all means take a rest.  No, in that if you have a shred of honour you wont want to let the hill defeat you :)

Comment: @Mr.Boy there is no shame in resting.  Even if you're the slowest person riding that day, you're faster than everyone who stayed at home.
The pro's don't stop for a rest because they're that fit, their resting happens on the less-steep bits or the downhills. My point on the ride logging is to see your progress in raw numbers.  Its awesome!

Comment: @Mr.Boy - The main problem with stopping on a hill is that you've got to get started again.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Right, and that might be a PITA with clipless pedals on steep hills, especially if one is not used to it.

Comment: @anderas - Generally one can get started without clipping in either shoe (by pedaling on the instep), if the circumstances are such that a "bail out" might be required.  But it's difficult in any case, if the hill is steeper than you are strong.  I will often start out going across the road (when traffic permits) or look for a driveway or some such in which to get up steam.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I completely agree, but when I started riding clipless and wasn't really used to it, both options felt a bit insecure. Actually what I'm doing now is exactly what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in your example of a 10% gradient and MTB gearing, it is easily possible to climb without going anaerobic.  It all comes down to your power to weight ratio at lactate threshold.

Following a training program including structured intervals will help improve your threshold power.  Interval sessions can also help your body become used to making hard efforts and then recovering ready to go again.

Comment: Yep. Plus skills to ride slowly. On a MTB the OP should be able to ride at 5kph (3mph) and still be in control. The certain way to go anaerobic is to rush at a hill. A bunch of questions under the [tag:climbing] tag also.